# Testing with RequestFactory seems to pass for non existing route

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mixins

I'm trying to verify if accessing routes of my Django application would return a 200 status code.

As I was writing repetitive test code, I search for some options and found that I could use [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.RequestFactory) with a *mixin*. But what I'm not understanding is why the test is not failing for a non existing route.
I have a class-based view called `IndexView` which I'm trying to test, but the idea is to use the *mixin* to test others as well.

The tests below will consider a non existing route called `i-dont-exist`:

##### Using `client`

What I see here is that I'm not using an instance of my view inside the test yet, but only the get to `i-dont-exist` route.

```py
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

from .. import views


class ExampleViewTest(TestCase):
    def test_if_route_exists(self):
        response = self.client.get('/i-dont-exist')
        status_code = response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
```

Running `python3 manage.py test`:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_if_route_exists (page.tests.test_views.ExampleViewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxx/page/tests/test_views.py", line 15, in test_if_route_exists
    self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

#### Using `RequestFactory`

Now I'm using my class-based view inside the test.

```py
class ViewMixinTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Every test needs access to the request factory.
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def get(self, view, url):
        request = self.factory.get(url)
        response = view.as_view()(request)
        status_code = response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(status_code, 200)


class OtherExampleViewTest(ViewMixinTest, TestCase):
    def test_if_route_exists(self):
        return self.get(views.IndexView, '/i-dont-exist')
```

Running tests again:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

I don't know why the pass is testing. I'm missing something?
Sorry, I'm new to tests.

Comment: you have passed the `request` directly to the `view` here. Why will it fail? It would fail if it couldn't detect an appropriate `urlpattern` to pass to the `view`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a long time ago and I think I resolved the problem in another way. Thanks